# Filter user details when clicking on a radio button?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

How can i filter user details when clicking on a radio button?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BNjPFR6O6PqlR24OzPQG?p=preview)

*Actually, I want to filter authenticate user questions in the list page, so I have created a plunker. If i'm an authenticated user (or) admin, I want to filter `myquestions` only in the list page.

**For Example :-** in plunker my `displayName` is `Table 1` means if I click `My Question` radio button, my questions only need to `filter`.

**My HTML radio button:-**

```
<input type="radio" name="myquestion" data-ng-model="myquestion.user.displayName" value="myquestion" >
```

**My HTML Filter:-**

```
    ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: myquestion"

**My Html Data:-**

<div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: myquestion">
    <small>
                      Posted on
                      <span data-ng-bind="question.created | date:'mediumDate'"></span>
                      <span data-ng-bind="question.user.displayName"></span>
                  </small>

  </div>
```

**My Controller Data:-**

```
$scope.questions = [
{
"_id": "583433ddc021a5d02949a51b",
"user": {
"_id": "5834336ac021a5d02949a51a",
"displayName": "mani R",
"location": "ICF",
"dob": "1991-10-05T18:30:00.000Z",
"religion": "Christian",
"roles": [
"user"
],
"profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
},
"__v": 0,
"upvoters": [],
"category": "Moral Ethics",
"content": "Dhoni",
"title": "which batsman is best in the world?",
"created": "2016-11-22T12:02:37.376Z"
},
{
"_id": "582c34b3ff26bd603e1e5383",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "Table 1",
"dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"location": "Icf",
"religion": "Hindu",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
},
"__v": 1,
"upvoters": [],
"users": [],
"comments": [
{
"created": 1479365394684,
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"name": "Table 1",
"commentText": "Dhoni"
}
],
"friend_tag": [],
"emotion": "Confused",
"category": "Environment & Health",
"content": "sachin?",
"title": "who is best player in this world?",
"created": "2016-11-16T10:28:03.859Z"
},
{
"_id": "582c3418ff26bd603e1e5382",
"user": {
"_id": "582c1f4b53cf7fec2ddf282e",
"displayName": "selvam R",
"dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"roles": [
"kp"
],
"profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
},
"__v": 0,
"upvoters": [],
"category": "Environment & Health",
"content": "he is tennis player",
"created": "2016-11-16T10:25:28.835Z"
},
{
"_id": "582ad554714543e037cf3bf2",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "Table 1",
"dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"location": "Icf",
"religion": "Hindu",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
},
"__v": 1,
"upvoters": [
"ms@e21designs.com"
],
"upvotes": 1,
"category": "Moral Ethics",
"created": "2016-11-15T09:28:52.403Z"
},
{
"_id": "5821e7c667b70aac2b8fdfdc",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "Table 1",
"dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"location": "Icf",
"religion": "Hindu",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
},
"__v": 1,
"upvoters": [
"ms@e21designs.com"
],
"upvotes": 1,
"category": "Religion & Culture",
"created": "2016-11-08T14:57:10.354Z"
}
]
```

- We tried `alt="{{vm.authentication.user.displayName}}"` but it's not working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what youre trying to do was to filter the list base on displayName of logged in user, right? I dont know if you guys have a service for user auth I just assume that Table 1 was the given logged in user. I use `ng-change` to detect if radio button is changed for me to filter all and myquestions.

on my controller:

```
$scope.authUser = {
    "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
    "displayName": "Table 1",
    "dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
    "location": "Icf",
    "religion": "Hindu",
    "roles": [
      "admin"
    ],
    "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
};
```

on html:

```
   <div class="col-md-3" id="donate">
      <label class="green">
        <input type="radio" name="myquestion" ng-model="myQuestion" value="myquestion" ng-change="stateChange(myQuestion)">
        <span>My Questions</span>
      </label>
      <label class="green">
        <input type="radio" name="myquestion" ng-model="myQuestion" value="all" ng-change="stateChange(myQuestion)">
        <span>All</span>
      </label>
   </div>

   <div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: { user.displayName: searchText }">
      <small>
        Posted on
        <span data-ng-bind="question.created | date:'mediumDate'"></span>
        <span data-ng-bind="question.user.displayName"></span>
      </small>
   </div>
```

For working sample I edited your plunkr. here is the link
http://plnkr.co/edit/U5M29NMfvtY0vTnQyjmT?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, please look at my plunker i have given the radio button over there , what we expecting `onclicking` of `radio button` it's should filter logged user questions only....for example `Table 1` is logged means the `table 1` details only need display... your  answer almost done.... but oncliking of radio button filter method is missing, so please help me for this... then we have `service` also so please give me the exact solution thanks....

Comment: Any solution? ...In my `local host` the filter is working perfectly using of this filter `ng-repeat="question in vm.questions | filter: vm.authentication.user.displayName" ` but what we expecting `on clicking` of `radio button` it's need to filter.... so how i use this in radio input filed...please look into my plunker and update the solution ...thanks..

Comment: sorry for late response. I updated my answer I hope It might help you.

Comment: just a little bit note: be careful on filtering without specifying the the field it might get wrong data because it compares on all fields :)